# Ansible check if directory acessible then do something

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

i want to include this logic in my role

```
- name: i want to check that NFS share is accessible and R/W
  module_to_check_nfs_share: touch {{ nfs_share_path }} ( for example , or cd to it)

- name: add NFS share path to elasticsearch config
  template: ...
  when: nfs_module == success
```

how to do something like this using the ansible? so my scenario is , to try write something or cd to NFS share and make sure that NFS filesystem is accessible and is ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `stat` module to see whether a directory exists and if it is writeable. `stat.writable` contains a boolean that is `true` when the directory exists **and** is writable.

```yaml
- name: Get directory status
  stat:
    path: /path/to/your/dir
  register: dirstatus

- name: Conditional task that only runs when dir exists and is writable
  template: ...
  when: dirstatus.stat.writeable | default(false)
```

Comment: Added the default filter so the conditionnal task does not fail in case the dir does not exist.